# Custom CSS class or ID on menu items that have a Submenu

Tags: css, menus

If I want to apply a style to only an item in a menu that has a submenu, how can I select that with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery, if you're open to a jQuery solution?

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('#your_menu_id li').has('ul').addClass('has_children');
});
</script>
```

Slight modification of what i posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5156/add-a-has-children-class-to-body-tag/5214#5214) basically.

Any menu item with a submenu will then have a `has_children` class you can target in the stylesheet..

```
#your_menu_id li.has_children { /* your styling */ }
#your_menu_id li.has_children ul { /* your styling */ }
#your_menu_id li.has_children ul li { /* your styling */ }
```

Hope that helps..

Answer (score 1):

Go to my menu area in admin, click the “Screen Options” link at the top, and check the “CSS Classes” then on each menu I’ll have an area I can define my css class for that menu item.
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a good solution if your pages aren't changing, but I'm dealing with users who are changing pages and won't remember to add the CSS class.

Comment: Yeah its for the less advanced users.